# Hive Dump and re load

Tags: hadoop, hive

Is there any way to make a Hive Table Dump such that table dump could be send across and re loaded into Hive , preserving the partition, bucketing structures ?

Answer (score 1):

Hive 0.8(and later) provides us the facility of `EXPORT`. Using this feature we can export the data from a table along with the corresponding metadata to an HDFS file. The data is stored in json format. Data once exported this way could be imported back to another database or hive instance using the `IMPORT` command.

See [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1918) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Tariq, export and import worked from command line,

But via Java Code it Export worked and import failed,
it says no such table. 

Via Java code I have to create a table of a schema and then import from the dumb..

Code//

HiveConf conf = new HiveConf();
SessionState.start(conf);
Driver dri = new Driver(conf);
dri.compile("import table newemp2 from 'hdfs://localhost:8020/user/backup/dump4'");
dri.execute();

Answer (score 0):

Basically you do one thing that is take the file(dump) which is loaded into hive table(say A) and consider that as the dump. Now while reloading that file into some other Hive table(say B) you can actually create B based on the previous Hive table i.e A. To create B similar to A you can use org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetastoreClient class to access the metastore information for the table A.You can then load the file(dump) and load into required partition.